# Import only certain rows of a data frame within read.csv function

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame "tm". I am trying to remove any rows where the value in that column is TOT. The code below does the job but I'm wondering if there is a way that I can do it in the read.csv function?

```
nba <- read.csv("~/Desktop/NBA Data/Advanced.csv") |> subset(tm != "TOT")
```

Comment: Using `subset()` is perfect here. I'm unaware of a way to do it via an argument in `read.csv()`. Do you have a reason for wanting to filter within `read.csv()`?

Comment: `read.csv()` as well as `read_csv()` and `fread()` only have arguments to skip columns or row numbers. What you already have may be the best way.

Comment: I agree with the other comments, what you have is among the best ways

Comment: If your file ("~/Desktop/NBA Data/Advanced.csv") is very large (i.e. larger than your RAM) you can pre-process the csv to filter out rows using `fread(cmd)`, e.g. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/how-data-tables-fread-can-save-you-a-lot-of-time-and-memory-and-take-input-from-shell-commands/

Comment: Depending on the actual motive of the question (general interest, style, performance, package selection, ... ) and dataset properties ( https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sumitrodatta/nba-aba-baa-stats ? < 5MB / 31k records / 32 columns / 9% "TOT" -  smallish, so doesn't really matter)  you may consider alternative loading methods, for example `data.tables` or `vroom`.  Some benchmarks just to get an idea of how things compare against `read.delim()` + base manipulation for different datasets:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html